# Make Saleor multitenant

Tags: django, multi-tenant, saleor, django-tenants

I'm currently working on an E commerce platform like shopify. I found tons of good reviews about saleor open source project , and went for it to speed up the development.
The plan i'm going with is to add Multitenancy to SaleOr with Django Tenants package. But I'm pretty new to SaleOr and can't find any proper tutorial about what i'm trying to do.

Does anyone here mind helping please ?
Reading and following the docs didn't help.
Any guidance is appreciated

I tried following the docs for installation but it's quite confusing for me.
A beginner comprehensive step by step guide or tutorial would be wonderful*.
Any form of kind assistance too.